# Relative Clause Tree Diagram

Tags: english, relative-clauses

My teacher drew this diagram in the class. He seperated the sentence as NP and S2 but it doesn't seem true. Can somebody help me?

[image: tree diagram]

Comment: You have to specify the reference. Which theory is your teacher lecturing, this structure might be correct in a PSG sense, but GB and MP do no recognize this type of parsing. Put simply, the complementizer has a distinct but embedded CP layer:

Comment: The lesson is Introduction to Linguistics and it's the first time analyzing sentences for me. He didn't teach any theory but I'm trying to understand x-bar. I didn't know there were different theories. I think I need to accept his method to pass the class.
Thank you by the way.

Comment: His method might be useful as a warming up for more intricate issues to come. You can't judge his method at its initial levels. You can read 'introduction to government & binding theory' by Liliane Haegman to understand issues more accurately as a syntactic course. Just don't go deep since this course is an introduction to linguistics not syntax. You can also read 'an Introduction to language' by Victoria Fromkin, a more general and useful book for introductory courses to linguistics.

Comment: Why doesn't it seem true? Please tell us your reason for saying this.  Notice what the antecedent of "which" is.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture—e.g., where does [NP a gray horse] connect to the tree?—but, based on the heights, this seems wrong in multiple ways. Can you edit the picture, or use something like [SynTree](http://mshang.ca/syntree/) to draw one for us?

Comment: This isn't a "make me a syntax tree" question. The OP _has_ a syntax tree, knows what it means, and is asking for help in interpreting the diagrammed syntax. The meta question linked from the close reason says "This only refers to questions asking the community to "do the homework for me". If you provide the tree yourself and ask questions about it (maybe you want a clarification or you have doubts about something), that is on topic." That seems to describe exactly this question. So I think it should be reopened.

Comment: Meanwhile, to the OP: This question could be improved by including the information TsuTsu, Greg Le, and I asked for in comments. Just responding in comments isn't enough; the question needs to be [edit]ed to be answerable even if the comments aren't there. I can't promise that this will get your question reopened (because I think it was closed inappropriately in the first place), but it might help—but, even if not, it's still worth learning to use SE the right way, so you'll get better answers on future questions.

Comment: I've opened [a meta question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/) on this. I think the help, as written, is misleading the people who voted to close here, and needs to be improved. (Or, if I'm wrong, then it's misleading _me_, and also at least one moderator, so it still needs to be improved…)

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell from your picture, because some of the lines are not really visible. But I'm pretty sure your confusion comes from the fact that your teacher is wrong, in multiple, fundamental ways:

- [which belonged to the old sailor] is modifying (part of) the object NP. You saw [a gray horse which belonged to the old sailor]. So that S2 needs to be inside the NP, as a sibling of what it's modifying. That's the whole point of relative clauses, and, more generally, of modifiers. Your teacher seems to have drawn it as a sibling of the subject, which would mean *you*, not the horse you saw, belonged to the old sailor. It's also apparently a child of the outer sentence, which makes no sense—what component of the sentence is it supposed to be? This sounds like the part you're asking about, and you're right to ask, because it makes no sense.
- Even more fundamentally: that object NP (including the relative clause) needs to be inside the VP (traditionally, as the direct sibling of the V). Objects are arguments of verbs; arguments go inside the phrase. I'm not sure where your teacher has put it; it seems to be not even linked into the sentence at all, which is never right for *anything*.
- Even *more* fundamentally: [S NP-subj VP] is the basic starting point for what a sentence is, and your teacher seems to have missed even that, and left the VP (with nothing in it but a V) floating around unattached.
- [gray horse] is definitely not an AdjP. It acts noun-ish, not adjective-ish, and it clearly means a kind of horse, not a kind of gray, so it's some kind of projection of the head [N horse], not [Adj gray].
- [old sailor] has the exact same problem as [gray horse].

This is not theory-specific stuff; it's part of the basic pre-theoretic model of the simple (surface) structure of sentences that different theories try to explain and represent in different ways.

As a first approximation, try this:

- [S [NP [Pronoun I]] [VP [V saw] [NP [D a] [AP [A gray]] [N horse] [S [C which] [VP [V belonged] [PP [P to] [NP [D the] [AP [A old]] [N man]]]]

[image: I saw a gray horse which belonged to the old man]

By the way, that diagram comes from the [Syntax Tree Generator by Miles Shang](http://mshang.ca/syntree/); you can just go to the web page, paste a bracket-notation tree, and it gives you the equivalent graphical tree. There are dozens of such programs, so I'm not specifically endorsing this one; you might, e.g., prefer one that lets you drag things around in the tree instead of forcing you to get the brackets right.

Comment: Abarnert, would you consider S [which belonged to the old man] an adjunct or an argument? And do you think there was a theta-role assigned to this clausal argument/adjunct?

Comment: I'd substitute NP for C over _which_ (I'd use C over _that_), and DP over D over _a_, if I were being as fancy with the DP as the AP, and NP over the subordinate S. But those are trivial diffs. This is good straightforward GS; McCawley would like it fine.

Comment: @jlawler I tried to stick with the teacher's categories, except when they were just blatantly wrong. Explaining those changes would require giving a lot more background, and committing to a specific theory. Explaining why the VP has to be somewhere inside the sentence instead of floating around as an unconnected tree is a lot simpler (and probably more important, too).

Comment: @TsutsuT. It's an adjunct, and it serves much the same function, in basically the same way, as "gray" here. The details depend on what your theory says about the argument structure of N—but by any measure, even taking the broadest theory, "gray horse" is a already a complete description. Restricting it to "gray horse which belonged to the old man" is the same as restricting it to "gray, tired horse". The relativizing test is kind of silly when applied to something that's already a relative clause, but: "a gray horse which was the one which belonged to the old man".

Comment: @TsutsuT. First consider this side track: You can't devour without something getting devoured; "*He devoured" but "He devoured the cookies". But "His frequent devouring bothered her" is possible. So in "his devouring of the cookies", we have to work out whether "cookies" is an optional argument or an adjunct, and, if the former, if "devouring" assigns a theta role; lots of theory follows. But "He is a horse" doesn't require ownership any more than color or age, and doesn't imply a default owner or color argument. So, in "horse which belonged to the old man", the same question doesn't come up.

Comment: Abarnert,  As far as I know, the syntactic theory like GB does not assume that adjuncts are assigned theta roles (Chomsky, 1981, 1986). However, some fishy notions are introduced in the same theory, considering the existence of nominal, prepositionl, and adjectival predicates. I'd say even these would be projected as adjuncts, so they must be assigned a theta role as well, this is what the semantic theory assumes. Theta theory, I think, is the most controversial of its kind during the 60s, even now. Borer (2005. 2013) emphasies that it should be removed completely, Chomsky (2007) doesn't.

Comment: @TsutsuT. Right, "theta role" is a theory-internal term, and within that theory, the answer is dead simple: No. The point of the side track was that, even if you toss theta theory, even if you toss GB, from a theory-neutral point of view, there's no semantic thematic role that "horse" selects/demands/subcategorizes/whatever and that the relative clause fulfills.

Comment: @TsutsuT. I'm not sure what your point is about predicates. Normally, in non-GB theories, you define the semantics of predicates as a function or lambda form that gets applied to the thing being modified. This allows them to be adjoined to anything that works as a parameter to the function/lambda. Many non-GB frameworks give relative clauses the same semantics, and therefore the same syntax, as predicates. If this is what you're getting at, then  yes—and that's exactly why they don't need anything equivalent to a "theta role".

Comment: @TsutsuT. Sorry, for "thing being modified" there I meant to say "thing being predicated", and then segue to predicates being used as modifiers having the same semantics, but I somehow jumped right over that…

Comment: @BillJ Let's take the discussion to [this meta](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/help-about-syntax-tree-questions-needs-to-be-improved). There are too many comments here that are not directly related to the question at hand. I'll be deleting all of them.